# Userform validation whilst been filled out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I currently have a userform

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Iflexcst", "Costing", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return (checkForm(this) && false);" }))
{
            <label for="NUM">Number of Sets:</label>
            <br>
            <input class="foo" id="NUM" type="text" value=@ViewBag.Quantity name="Quan" />

        <label for="CS"> Cost</label>

        <br>
        <input class="foo" id="CS" type="number" value=@ViewBag.result />


        <input type="submit" value="Cost" />
```

And a javascript that validates after i press the submit button

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkForm(form) {
        if (form.Quan.value == "") {
            alert("Error: Username cannot be blank!");
            form.username.focus();
            return false;
        }
        re = /^\w+$/;

    }

</script>
```

I want to the userform to not submit the data to the controller after doing the validaton, as my jquery currently returns the message but then still goes into the controller function which sends an error if NUM is empty.

If the above is an easy solve, would it also be possible to have it do the validation whilst  the form is been filled out, for example if a user enters a number < 10 the form instantly shows a pop up and wont let you submit till this error is fixed?

Comment: Why not just use jquery.validate.unobtrusive in conjunction with validation attributes and have all this done out of the box.

Comment: Will i need to install it with the nuget manager? and include in the bundles?

Comment: <input type="text" name="email" data-val="true" 
data-val-required="This field is required.">  

<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul><li style="display:none"></li></ul>
</div> like this?

Comment: It should already be included by default (and the included in `~/bundles/jqueryval`). And you need to learn to use models and bind to your models using html helpers. Go to the MVC site and work though the basic tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your javascript at the line

```
form.username.focus();
```

As there is no element in the form named "username" so when the statement

```
if (form.Quan.value == "")
```

gets true you try to focus an html element which does not exist in your form so before the return false line gets hit the browser returns an uncaught reference exception and the form goes to controller.

To fix the issue either remove the following line

```
 form.username.focus();
```

or change it to

```
 form.Quan.focus();
```

which will focus your Quan text box if it was empty and the form will not go to the controller.

Comment: Solved this earlier haha! but yeah thanks for the help ive give you the green tick of wisdom

Comment: Perfect! could be useful for someone else too :)